# What is the best simplification for a key that has a value, and also has sub keys in YAML?

Tags: spring, yaml

We're using YAML for our Spring Boot projects and I faced a situation where a value was assigned to a key, which also had sub keys like so:

```
parent.sub: value1
parent.sub.property1: someOtherValue
parent.sub.property2: blah
parent.sub.property3: youGetIt
```

Is there a way to simplify that in YAML so that the value is still assigned to the main property, but also to the sub-properties? I was thinking something like this, but clearly it didn't work:

```
parent:
  sub: value1
    property1: someOtherValue
    property2: blah
    property3: youGetIt
```

My IDE is IntelliJ. when I tried the above, the value and the key bellow get underlined with the error `Invalid child element in a block mapping`

The actual properties are just spring-boot logging levels, so here are the properties I'm trying to simplify:

```
logging.level.org.springframework: INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.web: INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.boot: DEBUG
```

It's not that big of a matter to have those specific properties spelled out, but I have faced other situations in the past where that kind of simplification would be more useful. So I'm wondering if it could be done at all

Comment: You're given example should work. What is the outcome that you think it doesn't? Maybe you tried to start the same node twice? Once you added a node, all chlidren must be placed inside (tha'ts YAML rules). But with Spring you can always add properties to an existing node later on, you then have to use the full dotted qualified name and can not use the tree style itself anymore.

Comment: IntelliJ underlines the value and the next line saying `Invalid child element in a block mapping`. I'll add that info in the question

Comment: @Slevin ahhh gotcha, so what I'm trying to do won't work then. could you post that as an answer, please?

Comment: Please give the full YAML config file, since there yould be a styling problem prior to the occurence of the error.

Comment: Just from a YAML perspective, each node has to be either a scalar (string, number, boolean, etc.) or a block item (a sequence/array or a map/object) containing further nodes (manifested as a subtree). In your second snippet, `property1`, `property2`, and `property3` contain scalars (strings), while `parent` contains a map with sub-items. `sub`, however, tries to be both, as it contains a string **and** another map (hence the error, imo), which (just by the YAML specs) is not valid YAML (yet, as I don't know Spring, I can't tell if it could indeed accept such structures, nevertheless).

Answer (score 0):

Once you've created a specific `node` you have to place all childs inside it. That's how common YAML works. Although, Spring provides you with an escape to this rule, but you then have to add further childs in full qualified dot-notation Style. So this would work:

```yaml
# intruducing the node `parent` to the YAML tree
parent:
  sub: value1
    property1: someOtherValue
    property2: blah
    property3: youGetIt

# further ongoing settings

# adding more properties to the `parent` node
parent.sub.property4: moreValues
parent.sub.property5: lotMoreValues
```

An additional note: Using the Jackson YAML parser you are not able to parse the provided solution. Spring uses `snakeYaml` and adds some internal processing to make this work. Bear that in mind if you wanna parse `YAML` files on your own. You can always use Springs Parser but then without the benefit of processing/altering the nodes directly. However, for simple customization/properties files this is all ok.